calendar event not added from appscript
I have the following code in Apps Script to create a calendar event when entries are added to a google sheet, I followed a Youtube video and the code is like for like with just entry numbers changed.
I keep getting the following error when running the script:










8:05:58 PM
Error
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String,(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent. (anonymous)    @ Code.gs:9 createCalendarEvent @ Code.gs:8



CODE:
function createCalendarEvent() {
  let pawsomedogCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("info.pawsomedogcare@gmail.com");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0,2);

  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
    pawsomedogCalendar.createEvent(entry[40],entry[3],entry[4],entry[42],entry[43],entry[44]);
  });
}

GOOGLESHEET LINK:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13GuDYE2tRWbwhA2o3M9mAfL0AGh7zfAdFalIQ8HSCQQ/edit?usp=sharing

While a link to a spreadsheet might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Please add sample input data directly into the question body.

An answer has been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

Event creation in Google Calendar
In order to create an event with Google Calendar these certain parameters must be met.
createEvent(title, startTime, endTime)

Based on the code that you have provided, the parameters are not used properly. Also, since you are referring the date and time values to your data in Google Sheets, it needs to be converted to Date object before being used. In this code, the values are being passed directly, which will cause errors or unexpected behavior as the createEvent method cannot handle string inputs directly for date and time.
Here is the updated code you can use.
function createCalendarEvent() {
 let pawsomedogCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("sampleCalendarId@sample.com"); //Please insert the correct Calendar ID
 let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 schedule.splice(0,1); // Since you only have 1 header row in your provided sheet, you only have to remove one.

 schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
   var title = entry[40];
   //Converting the String cell values into Date objects
   var startDate = new Date(entry[43]);
   var endDate = new Date(entry[44]);

   pawsomedogCalendar.createEvent(title, startDate, endDate);
 });
}

Feel free to visit these public documentations and video for your references:

createEvent
Splice
Video to get the Calendar ID

